# Convert javascript function to php (custom sort)

Tags: javascript, php

I have this code in php.

```
$nameList = array();
for ($j = 1; $j <= nameList; $j++) {
    //DO the sort here
}
return $nameList;
```

Now I want to do the below javascript but I want to do it on the PHP array $nameList, so how can I do the below code in PHP syntax? That is I want to create a regex where I filter away all digits on each row and compare the letters where the "higher" letters come first in the array.

```
var nRegex = /\d/g;
nameList.sort(function(a, b) { a = a.replace(nRegex, ""); b = b.replace(nRegex, ""); 
return b.localeCompare(a); 
});
```

Comment: why dont you just use the php array sort functions like usort?

Comment: Have a look at [usort](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) and [strcmp](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strcmp.php).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$nRegex = '/\d/';

function cmp($a, $b) {

    $a = preg_replace($nRegex, '', $a );
    $b = preg_replace($nRegex, '', $b );

    return strcmp($a, $b);
}

usort($a, "cmp");
```